# WooCommerce Remove WordPress Header lines

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am just about to launch an eCommerce site using WordPress and WooCommerce and trying to tidy up the source code and strip out all the WordPress header lines.

The site is pure eCommerce with a blog for users and search engines, I believe the functions below are for a pure blog website.

```
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"/>

<link rel="pingback" href="http://www.domain.co.uk/xmlrpc.php"/>

<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.domain.co.uk/xmlrpc.php?rsd"/>

<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://www.domain.co.uk/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml"/>
```

Does anyone know what is required from the above for WordPress to function?  And how we can remove these from WordPress, if we can?

Thanks Kindly.

J

Comment: Are you not seeing these listed in your header.php file?

Comment: Hi They are in the Header files, but before I remove I want to be certain I am not breaking anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely remove all of these from your **header.php** file. They aren't required for the site to function.

More info: In HTML5, the "profile" attribute was [dropped](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-head-profile).

The others are purely optional.

For de-registering the bottom two, you'll need to add some new lines to your **functions.php**:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
```

These functions, from the `wp_head` action hook, can be viewed in [wp-includes/general-template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L2190), starting on line 2190.

From this file, `rsd_link` "display(s) the link to the [Really Simple Discovery service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Really_Simple_Discovery) endpoint."

The `wlmanifest_link` "display(s) the link to the Windows Live Writer manifest file." If you don't use Windows Live Writer, there's no need for this.

Comment: Thanks, Where do I remove the last 2 they dont seem to be called in my Themes header.php.  They seem to be coming from wp_head() ?

Comment: To remove those, you'll have to deregister them via your functions.php: `remove_action ('wp_head', 'rsd_link');` and `remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');`